# 502 Nginx - Error - Bytes Sent

Tags: php, nginx

I'm having a problem with Nginx.
From time to time it's showing *502 - Bad Gateway*, when i see the `access.log`, I see this:

> "GET /play.php?games=naruto HTTP/1.1" 502 584
>   "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0
>   Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"

> Error.log: 2016/12/12 10:28:01 [crit] 1463#1463: *968 connect() to
>   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.10, server: _, request:
>   "GET /play.php?games=naruto HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "playnaruto.com"

I realize it's showing me 502, everytime the bytes sent is 584 or 182.
I'm trying to solve it but i don't know how.

Comment: Check php-fpm logfiles.

Comment: does `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` exists?

Comment: It's strange the file was there and now it isn't anymore. Yesterday i remembered that I gave permission 755 to this folder and file. But how do i put it again?